# где нужно смотреть размер файлов

Tags: windows, файловая-система

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть папка в ней файлы. где нужно смотреть её размер в
"Размер:"
или "На диске:"

вообще если "Размер:" и "На диске:" отличаются

что вообще значит "На диске:"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы на диске хранятся кластерами. Размер кластера определяется при создании раздела диска. Файл может занимать только целое число кластеров. Отсюда разница.

Например, если размер кластера 4096 байт, а размер файла 1 байт, то на диске он будет занимать 4096 байт. Если размер файла 4097 байт, то на диске он занимает 8192 байта.

Противоположный пример - разреженные (sparsed) файлы. Это файлы с пустым содержимым. Например, в файле может быть заполнены только первые 10 байт, потом с 3000 до 3200 и и с 1024*1024*1024 до 1024*1024*1024 + 10 байт. Тогда размер файла будет 1024*1024*1024 + 10 байт, а на диске он будет занимать 30 байт (если не ошибаюсь, то разреженные файлы не выравниваются на размер кластера)

Третий случай: на NTFS файлы могут состоять из набора потоков (Alternate Data Stream - ADS). Так вот, файловые менеджеры показывают только один главный поток, а место занимают все.

Четвертый случай - это символические ссылки. Когда физически файл лежит в одном месте, а из разных мест на него указывают ссылки. Тогда для каждой ссылки будет указан размер реального файла, но на диске он будет занимать место только один раз.

Пятый случай - это сжатые NTFS папки. Когда физически вся папка упаковывается в один zip архив. Тогда во-первых физический размер файла уменьшается из-за сжатия, а во-вторых выравнивание по кластеру работает уже не для каждого отдельного файла, а для всего архива

P.S. Как оказалось, альтернативные потоки Explorer тоже не видит и показывает размер на диске только для основного потока

P.S.2 Похоже в современных системах с выравниванием на размер кластера все не так просто. На скриншоте обычный файл размером 10 байт в Windows 10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое ощущение, что маленькие файлы теперь хранятся в каком-то общем кластере

Comment: хе, т.е. могут быть обманки-неточности... мда.

Comment: @olgabulanovva в 90% случаев расхождение получается из-за выравнивания на границу кластера

Answer (score 2):

"Размер" может быть любым (в пределах доступного диска). Это и есть размер файла.

"На диске" может быть только кратным определенному числу, т.к. хранение файлов на диске организуется [кластерами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)), и минимальный размер, который файл будет занимать на диске, равен размеру кластера.

Поэтому "на диске" почти всегда больше, чем "размер" (они будут равными только в том случае, когда размер файла точно равен какому-то целому количеству кластеров, например, 4кб, или 32кб). Если у вас сохранен текстовый файл с одной буквой, то "размер" будет 1 байт, а "на диске" будет равно размеру кластера. Например, размер кластера диска на изображении ниже равен 4кб.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавлю, что «на диске» может быть и меньше, чем «размер» при использовании сжатия на уровне ФС, при наличии дыр в файлах или жёстких ссылок на один файл для каталога...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да верно. У андроидных сдк. сжатых средствами системы, "на диске" примерно в два раза меньше, чем "размер".